# Is this suggested edit merited?

Tags: discussion

[image: How on earth was this edit approved?]

The only changes in this suggested edit that got approved 2-1 were that "Lilypond" in the title was changed to "LilyPond" (capitalised the P) and changed "PianoStaff" to "`PianoStaff`". Can someone explain how that edit is valid, in the face of

> *This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.*

, from our edit suggestion rejection message?

Answer (score 4):

The OP was posted on 2 Oct 2019 and edited on 21 Oct, 19 days later. Is a 19-day-old question too old for it to be worth editing it? Was this edit part of a spree of edits to old questions that caused the front page to be flooded with old questions? If not, I don't see that the edit did any harm, and therefore I don't see that it was wrong to do the edit.

BTW the edit changed PianoStaff to `PianoStaff`: the S was correctly a cap S both before and after the edit.